# How to add some padding for a block in IAR linker configuration file

Tags: sections, iar, linker-scripts

I am working on an IAR project. In its linker configuration file, a block is defined as the following

```
define block MY_BLOCK with alignment = 32 { section myblock };
place in CODE_RAM { block MY_BLOCK };
```

This created a `MY_BLOCK` memory object with 32 byte alignment， which is linked into physical memory `CODE_RAM`.

What I want to achieve is, leaving some extra padding area (say 64 bytes) in the end of the block. The block definition directive have the `size` parameter, if I want the `MY_BLOCK` size to grow to 1024, I can use

```
define block MY_BLOCK with alignment = 32, size = 1024 { section myblock };
```

And it works well.

However, I want the size to be `relative` to the original size. So I use

```
define block MY_BLOCK with alignment = 32, size = __section_size(section myblock) + 64 { section myblock };
```

This time linker report a error

```
Error[Lc009]: "__section_size" undefined
```

Looks like `__section_size` can be only used in C instead of linker configuration file.

In comparision, ARMGCC we can simply use

```
. = . + 64
```

in linker file to achieve this purpose. I am wondering if it is achievable in IAR.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to create an empty block with the padding and add it to `MY_BLOCK`. To ensure that the content and the padding are placed in the order listed in the file we add the attribute `fixed order` to `MY_BLOCK`. We also need to add `keep { block MY_PADDING };` to the configuration file to tell the linker to include `MY_PADDING` even though its content is not referenced from the application. The result looks something like this:

```
define block MY_PADDING with size = 64 {};
define block MY_BLOCK with alignment = 32, fixed order { section myblock,
                                                         block MY_PADDING };
keep { block MY_PADDING };
place in CODE_RAM { block MY_BLOCK };
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfect. I once thought of adding a filling data structure in C code to achieve similar effect, but a filling block in linker configuration file is of course more elegant